# Debian basic daemon not working

Tags: java, linux, service, debian, daemon

I've written a simple java program, which prints to log every few seconds, infinite `while` loop, with `Thread.sleep()`.
Running it like `java -jar ScheduledTask.jar` does the expected, prints to file.
I've wrapped the jar as suggested [HERE](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/linux-java-service-wrapper-example) , put it in `/etc/init.d/test1`, `test1` is my wrapper file, and ran `sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/test1`.

`test1` shows in the `service --status-all` list

However, when I run `sudo service test1 start` it does not do the printing.
I can provide the java code, but again all it does is printing to the file.
Log file is located in `/usr/local/test1/test.log`

The system is Debian 8(on AWS) with root privileges. Everything is done via the terminal(putty).

What can be wrong?

Wrapper:

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE_NAME=test1
PATH_TO_JAR=/usr/local/test1/ScheduledTask.jar
PID_PATH_NAME=/tmp/test1-pid
case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
        if [ ! -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    stop)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stoping ..."
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..."
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    restart)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopping ...";
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ...";
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME starting ..."
            nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
esac
```

Java code:

```
public class BaseServiceEngine {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("program started");
        FileWriter fw = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        String filePath = "/usr/local/test1/test.log";
        String osname = System.getProperty("os.name", "").toLowerCase();
        if (osname.startsWith("windows")) {
            filePath = "C:\\Development\\VS2012\\TFS\\ProjectCX\\WorkSpace.Alex.Main\\ProxyServers\\ProxyConfigurationService\\test.log";
        } else if (osname.startsWith("linux")) {
            filePath = "/usr/local/test1/test.log";
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, failed to locate file");
            return;
        }
        File logFile = new File(filePath);
        try {
            logFile.createNewFile();
            fw = new FileWriter(filePath, true);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            writer = new PrintWriter(bw);
            writer.println("Service started: " + new Date());
            final int runEveryXMillisecond = 20000;

            int i = 0;
            boolean runService = true;
            Date startTime = new Date();
            System.out.println("starting to print to filePath");
            while (runService) {
                Thread.sleep(2500);
                if (new Date().getTime() - startTime.getTime() >= runEveryXMillisecond) {
                    writer.println("Process run");
                }
                Date now = new Date();
                writer.println("service Time :" + now + "__loop:" + i++);
                writer.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getCause());
        } finally {
            try {
                writer.close();
                bw.close();
                fw.close();
            } catch (IOException | NullPointerException ex) {  }
        }
        System.exit(0);
        System.out.println("Exiting");
    }
}
```

`sudo service test1 status` returns:

> test1.service - (null)    Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/test1)
>   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-05-11 09:55:23 UTC; 1min 0s
>   ago   Process: 26062 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/test1 start (code=exited,
>   status=0/SUCCESS)    CGroup: /system.slice/test1.service
>              └─26063 java -jar /usr/local/test1/ScheduledTask.jar /tmp
>
> May 11 09:55:23 ip-10-0-0-115 test1[26062]: Starting test1 ... May 11
>   09:55:23 ip-10-0-0-115 test1[26062]: test1 started ... May 11 09:55:23
>   ip-10-0-0-115 systemd[1](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/linux-java-service-wrapper-example): Started (null).

Comment: whats the output of `sudo service test1 start` and please put script code in question

Comment: there is no output. `sudo service test1 status` gives:
● test1.service - (null)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/test1)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-05-11 09:55:23 UTC; 1min 0s ago
  Process: 26062 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/test1 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/test1.service
           └─26063 java -jar /usr/local/test1/ScheduledTask.jar /tmp

May 11 09:55:23 ip-10-0-0-115 test1[26062]: Starting test1 ...
May 11 09:55:23 ip-10-0-0-115 test1[26062]: test1 started ...
May 11 09:55:23 ip-10-0-0-115 systemd[1]: Started (null).

Comment: I mean to say Wrapper script code. please add it to question

Comment: name of jar is `test.jar` or `SheduledTask.jar` ? please post java code as well.

Comment: It's ScheduledTask.jar. The daemon is called test1 though

Comment: try running `nohup java -jar /usr/local/test1/ScheduledTask.jar /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null` on command line and see what it is doing

Comment: It is working now! Didn't change a thing...just looked at the logs and here they were. I guess something was stuck ,but it is working now. Thanks anyway Sanjeev!

Comment: Great.. Have fun coding